# Get all events related to a VMs (VCenter)

Tags: java, vsphere, vcenter

I am using [VSphere Automation SDK](https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk/) 6.7 for Java to develop a handler of some VMs and Datacenters.

I was doing pretty fine until I wanted to retrieve the following:

1. Gather all events related to a VM (I already have the code to distinguish the type but I cannot get all events)
2. Is there any way to list the services running in a VM?

Can anyone help me please? I am not sure if I need to add another API for doing such things.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Tasks and Events aren't yet available through the [vSphere Automation SDKs](https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/7.0/vsphere-management), which does include Java. However, they are available through the vSphere Management SDKs when using the vSphere Web Services API. Particularly the [EventManager service](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.event.EventManager.html)

For services, check out the [GuestProcessManager](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.html) service. As long as the VM has VMware Tools installed, you'll be able to use that to see what processes are actively running.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I will download that SDK and will take a look a those classes. Thanks again.